# How to create a Throwables<T,R>?

Tags: java, generics

I am having a hard time figuring out why this below code isn't working:

```
private static interface ThrowablesFunction<T, R> {
    public R swallow(Function<T, R> function, T str);
}

private static ThrowablesFunction<Function<String, Integer>, String> throwables = (function, string) -> {
    return 0; // error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String"
};
```

I am confused because it should return `R` and not `T`. It is expecting `T`.

But compiler has no problem with this:

```
private static interface ThrowablesFunction2 {
    public Integer swallow(Function<String, Integer> function, String str);
}

private static ThrowablesFunction2 throwables2 = (function, string) -> {
    return 0;
};
```

The main intention is to create a type that will swallow exceptions. But I am curious why does this happen?

Comment: Because the first return type is String, and the second is Integer. Not sure what's surprising.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. I have updated the question shmosel.

Comment: It should return R and not T. It is expecting T.

Comment: `R` in `ThrowablesFunction<T, R>` is  declared as `String`. Both functions need to return the same type if they both return `R`.

Comment: Are you creating this as some kind of hobby or test, or are you on a path to create a design flaw? I can see mainly worrying use cases for a generic type that will swallow exceptions, except for toying around or maybe something very peculiar (in which case I'd be interested in hearing about the use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ThrowablesFunction` doesn't do what you think it does. Take a look at `interface ThrowablesFunction`, it has two types `T` and `R`. Now when you do `ThrowablesFunction<Function<String, Integer>, String>`, the instance `throwables` expect you to send a `Function<Function<String, Integer>>` and not `Function<String,Integer>`. To solve this issue change your `throwables` to:

```
private static ThrowablesFunction<String, Integer> throwables = (function, string) -> {
    return 0; // or function.apply(string);
};

// invoke the throwables likewise
Integer integer = throwables.swallow(Integer::parseInt, "2");
```